# How to make scroll map in XNA (2D)?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a map, containing many objects in an area sized 5000*5000.
my screen size is 800*600.

how can i scroll my map, i don't want to move all my objects left and right, i want the "camera" to move, But unfortunately i didn't found any way to move it.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152662/having-the-background-or-camera-scroll-based-on-charcter-position/12167478#12167478

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I think you are looking for the `transformMatrix` parameter to `SpriteBatch.Begin` ([this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx)).**

You say you don't want the *objects* to move, but you want the *camera* to move. But, at the lowest level, in both 2D and 3D rendering, there is no concept of a "camera". Rendering always happens in the same region - and you must use transformations to place your vertices/sprites into that region.

If you want the effect of a camera, you have to implement it by moving *the entire world* in the opposite direction.

Of course, you don't actually *store* the moved data. You just apply an offset when you render the data. Emartel's answer has you do that for each sprite. However using a matrix is cleaner, because you don't have to duplicate the code for every single `Draw` - you just let the GPU do it.

To finish with an example: Say you want your camera placed at (100, 200). To achieve this, pass `Matrix.CreateTranslation(-100, -200, 0)` to `SpriteBatch.Begin`.

(Performing a frustum cull yourself, as per emartel's answer, is probably a waste of time, unless your world is *really* huge. See [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9289/288) for an explanation of the performance considerations.)

Answer (score 7):

**Viewport**

You start by creating your camera viewport. In the case of a 2D game it can be as easy as defining the bottom left position where you want to start rendering and expand it using your screen resolution, in your case `800x600`.

```
Rectangle viewportRect = new Rectangle(viewportX, viewportY, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

Here's an example of what your camera would look like if it was offset off `300,700` (the drawing is very approximate, it's just to give you a better idea)

[image: Viewport]

**Visibility Check**

Now, you want to find every sprite that intersects the `red square`, which can be understood as your `Viewport`. This could be done with something similar to (this is untested code, just a sample of what it could look like)

```
List<GameObject> objectsToBeRendered = new List<GameObject>();
foreach(GameObject obj in allGameObjects)
{
    Rectangle objectBounds = new Rectangle(obj.X, obj.Y, obj.Width, obj.Height);
    if(viewportRect.IntersectsWith(objectBounds))
    {
        objectsToBeRendered.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Here's what it would look like graphically, the green sprites are the ones added to `objectsToBeRendered`. Adding the objects to a separate list makes it easy if you want to sort them from `Back` to `Front` before rendering them!

[image: Visible]

**Rendering**

Now that we found which objects were intersecting we need to figure out where on the screen the will end up.

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
foreach(GameObject obj in objectsToBeRendered)
{
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(obj.X - viewportX, obj.Y - viewportY);
    spriteBatch.Draw(obj.GetTexture(), pos, Color.White);
}
spriteBatch.End();
```

As you can see, we deduce the `X` and `Y` position of the viewport to bring the world position of the object into `Screen Coordinates` within the viewport. This means that the small square that could be at `400, 800` in `World Coordinates` would be rendered at `100, 100` on the screen given the viewport we have here.

**Edit:**

While I agree with the change of "correct answer", keep in mind that what I posted here is still very useful when deciding which animations to process, which AIs to update, etc... letting the camera and the GPU make the work alone prevents you from knowing which objects were actually on screen!

Comment: This is what i'm trying to avoid.
if my resolution is 800*600 Xna is rendering everything the lies in a rectangle originated in 0,0 and ends in 800,600 .. 
i want him to render to the screen everything the the lies in a rectangle originated in 100,100 and ends in 900,700
how to do it ?

Comment: You're trying to avoid moving the objects around... if you move your camera, it's `clipping Rect` will move as well. When you want to render the objects, you will have to transform them from one set of coordinates to another (world space to screen space), that's where you will be removing the `top` and `left from your camera `clipping Rect`. The sprites remain the same in the world, but you're mapping them differently so they match pixels on the screen.

Comment: i know how to calculate the screen position when i move the camera. but i want to avoid this calculations, i want to tell XNA to move his camera to a specific location and then he will be responsible to the clipping and calculation of where and what to draw.
When you develop in 3d you dont move the world around, you just move the camera. i want to achive the same thing in 2D, but as i see.. XNA does't support this.

Comment: It's the same thing in 2D and 3D... when you do 3D, you need to `transform` your objects within the frustum to cull them, it's not moving them around, I don't see why you keep referring to that.

Comment: Ok, i understood what you meant.
i thought i could avoid using "obj.X-viewportX"

Comment: @OopsUser I think my answer might clarify things a bit.